# Can I use Jsoup to parse without enforcing strict HTML rules? (block element within <p> tag?)

Tags: jsoup

I have a need to take HTML that looks like this:

```
<p> <span> <ul> <li>LIST ELEMENT</li> </ul> </span> </p>
```

... and parse it while retaining that DOM hierarchy.

When I parse the above, Jsoup spits out:

```
<span></span><ul><li>LIST ELEMENT></li></ul>
```

I have tried parsing the original HTML in various HTML validators, and they all say that it is invalid and do the same thing.  This I know, but I need to retain this invalid markup.

Is there any setting I can set in Jsoup to make it retain this hierarchy, despite it being invalid?

Answer (score 1):

Try the [Xml Parser](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/parser/Parser.html#xmlParser%28%29) instead of the default html one.

> `public static Parser xmlParser()`
>
> Create a new XML parser. This parser assumes no knowledge of the incoming tags and does not treat it as HTML, rather creates a simple
>   tree directly from the input.
>
> **Returns:**
>
> ```
>     a new simple XML parser.
> ```

*source: http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/parser/Parser.html#xmlParser%28%29*

Example:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html, "", Parser.xmlParser());
```

Comment: I'll check it out, thanks!  Can the XML parser deal with unclosed HTML elements (eg. <p> without a closing </p> etc?).

Comment: I think so, normally it will close them.